# How do I display the actual image rather than black boxes?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to use the following code to insert three pictures horizontally - the code compiles perfectly, but the images are coming out as black boxes/rectangles.  I've made sure that the images are in the same file as the `.tex` document - what am I doing wrong?  I would really appreciate and help I can get.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{delete_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ok_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{settings_gesture.png}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `demo` package option in

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

From the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) (section **4.1 Package Options**):

> **`demo`**
>
> Instead of inserting an image file `\includegraphics` draws a 150 pt by
>   100 pt rectangle unless other dimensions are specified manually.